# How to transform variable-length password to fixed length secret key

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-encryption

Normally a password would be arbitrary strings, such as "abc", "1234". But the encryption algorithm like DES requires a fixed length secret key. I'd like to know how to transform variable-length password to fixed length secret key with an acknowledged way.

Answer (score 3):

Derive encryption keys from passwords with a Password Based Key Derivation Function: `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`). Use a random salt and an iteration count such that the derivation takes about 100ms of computation time.

The same salt and iteration count must be used for deriving the key for decryption, they can be prepended to the encrypted data since they do not need to be secret.

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.

The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: "about 100ms of computation time"... on what hardware, at what level of parallel compute resources, ...?

Comment: 100 ms on the production machine, that is about right for human usage. Sure a faster computer will do better but compared to <1us for SHA512 there is a big penalty for an attacker, ~100,000 times slower. See NIST [Recommendation for Password-Based Key Derivation](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf),  here is an excerpt: *The number of iterations should be set as high as can be tolerated for the environment, while maintaining acceptable performance.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a salt value (in order to prevent dictionary attacks) and good key deviation function like **scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2**.

if you only use a hash function for generating the key, then there are a lot of chances that the generated keys are SHA256("abcd") or SHA256("password"). That is, this method is very vulnerable to brute-force attacks.